# Sensio:FrameworkExtraBundle:Security not found/working

Tags: php, symfony

I've been having this issue for a while now.

Using the annotation as described in the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html) doesn't work.

If my config.yml reads:

```
sensio_framework_extra:
  security: { annotations: true }
```

when I install/update with composer I get an error saying:

```
Unrecognized options "security" under "sensio_framework_extra"
```

Including Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security doesn't work as well.
When I try to load the page, the following error occurs:

```
The annotation "@Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security" in method Poleis\CoreBundle\Controller\SchoolController::newAction() does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.)
```

config.yml:

```
sensio_framework_extra:
    view: { annotations: false }
    security: { annotations: true }
```

SchoolController.php:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
...

/**
 * @Route("/new", name="school_new")
 * @Template()
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')")
 */
public function newAction() {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this is happening is because `@Security` annotation does not exist in version [2.3.* of FrameworkExtraBundle](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/tree/2.3/Configuration)!

You can try using [JMSSecurityExtraBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/1.1/annotations) instead.

Comment: I accidentally flagged this as "Not an Answer" (I meant to flag another answer for this question). To aggravate the situation, I can't seem to retract the flag. Sorry about that.